# In corda enterprise can we use IBM MQ instead of ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: corda

I have gone through [this documentation](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.7/enterprise/node/corda-firewall-component.html#standalone-artemis-server), but I just need to check will IBM MQ work?

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Can you please provide me additional details on your requirement for using IBM MQ, so that I will convey it to the product team.